# Mongo showing on php info but MongoClient not working?

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I'm using a Mac and I've installed the Mongo Driver for PHP (5.3.1, my version). It shows up on php info but when I use it in my PHP script it wont work.

Here is what my PHP info shows:

```
MongoDB Support enabled
Version 1.0.11

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mongo.allow_empty_keys  0   0
mongo.allow_persistent  1   1
mongo.auto_reconnect    1   1
mongo.chunk_size    262144  262144
mongo.cmd   $   $
mongo.default_host  localhost   localhost
mongo.default_port  27017   27017
mongo.long_as_object    0   0
mongo.native_long   0   0
mongo.utf8  1   1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "when I use it in my PHP script it wont work". You may have separate `php.ini` files for the CLI and web environments, so it's possible the extension isn't available in both. Viewing `phpinfo()` output or `phpversion('mongo')` in the web environment should indicate if the extension is loaded or not. The next test would be determining if the MongoClient class exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the version of mongo listed in phpinfo is 1.2 -- MongoClient class wasn't out until v1.3

if so, you need to update mongodb to the newer version.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mongo/+bug/1096587